# Can a thread run a recursion that is called by the method assigned to it?

Tags: c#, multithreading, recursion, unity-game-engine

This may be a silly question and I couldn't find an answer around for a while.

Basically: I got a method that creates a thread that calls a method that calls a recursion, ....does this recursion run? because what I get from it is garbage...
I code in c# for unity3d. the script I want to run on a separate thread does not contain unity api methods.

---

#### Elaboration:

This is what I have:

The method `GetPCNextTurn` creates the thread like this:

```
Thread myThread = new Thread(() => CompPlayTurn(MinMaxBoard, weights));
myThread.Start();
```

Then `CompPlayTurn` should start right?

`CompPlayTurn` calls `ScoreBoard` which returns a value.

then after some condition `CompPlayTurn` calls a **recursion** which calls `ScoreBoard` recursivly

I would assume at this point it returns to the first method after the thread start lines right?

Something does not seem to happen the way I wish it would it seems. Can someone please enlighten me with behavior of threads and recursions?

I need 1 thread for this recursion all I need is to separate it from the main thread.

This is the code:
this is the main method in the script:

```
  public int GetPCNextTurn(int[][] board, int height, int width, int sequence)
    {
        this.done = false;
        this.height = height;
        this.width = width;
        this.sequence = sequence;

        int[][] MinMaxBoard = CopyBoard(board);

        weights = GetWeights(sequence);

        Thread myThread = new Thread(() => CompPlayTurn(MinMaxBoard, weights));
        myThread.Start();

        return ans;
    }

public void CompPlayTurn(int[][] MinMaxBoard, int[] weights)      
    {        
        int scoreOrig = ScoreBoard(MinMaxBoard);

        if (scoreOrig == orangeWins) winner = (int)Winner.pc;
        //     Debug.Log("I win\n");

        else if (scoreOrig == yellowWins) winner = (int)Winner.player;
           // Debug.Log("You win\n");

        else
        {
            int move, score;

            Minimax(true, (int)Mycell.Orange, maxDepth, MinMaxBoard, out move, out score);
            ans = move;

            if (move != -1)
            {
                ans = move;
                //    dropDisk(board, move, (int)Mycell.Orange);

                scoreOrig = ScoreBoard(MinMaxBoard);
                if (scoreOrig == orangeWins) { winner = (int)Winner.pc; }//Debug.Log("I win\n"); }
                else if (scoreOrig == yellowWins) { winner = (int)Winner.player; }//Debug.Log("You win\n"); }

            }
            else winner = (int)Winner.draw;
        }
    }

 public int ScoreBoard(int[][] scores)
    {
        int[] counters;
        int x, y, count = 0, size = (2 * sequence + 1);
        counters = new int[size];

        Array.Clear(counters, 0, counters.Length); //needed?

        // Horizontal spans
        for (y = 0; y < height; y++)
        {
            int score = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i <= sequence - 2; i++)
                score += scores[y][i];

            for (x = (sequence - 1); x < width; x++)
            {
                score += scores[y][x];
                counters[score + sequence]++;
                score -= scores[y][x - (sequence - 1)];
            }
        }

        // Vertical spans
        for (x = 0; x < width; x++)
        {
            int score = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i <= sequence - 2; i++)
                score += scores[i][x];

            for (y = (sequence - 1); y < height; y++)
            {
                score += scores[y][x];
                counters[score + sequence]++;
                score -= scores[y - (sequence - 1)][x];
            }
        }
        // Down-right (and up-left) diagonals
        for (y = 0; y < height - (sequence - 1); y++)
        {
            for (x = 0; x < width - (sequence - 1); x++)
            {
                int score = 0, idx = 0;
                for (idx = 0; idx < sequence; idx++)
                {
                    score += scores[y + idx][x + idx];
                }
                counters[(score + sequence)]++;
            }
        }
        // up-right (and down-left) diagonals
        for (y = (sequence - 1); y < height; y++)
        {
            for (x = 0; x < width - (sequence - 1); x++)
            {
                int score = 0, idx = 0;
                for (idx = 0; idx < sequence; idx++)
                {
                    score += scores[y - idx][x + idx];
                }
                counters[(score + sequence)]++;
            }
        }
        if (counters[0] != 0)
            return yellowWins;
        else if (counters[(sequence * 2)] != 0)
            return orangeWins;


        else
        {

            for (int i = 1; i < size - 1; i++)
            { count += weights[i] * counters[i]; }

            return count;
        }

    }

 public void Minimax(bool maximizeOrMinimize, int color, int depth, int[][] MinMaxBoard, out int move, out int score)
    {
        if (0 == depth)
        {
            move = -1;

            score = ScoreBoard(MinMaxBoard);
        }
        else
        {               
            int bestScore = maximizeOrMinimize ? -10000000 : 10000000;
            int bestMove = -1;


            for (int column = 0; column < width; column++)
            {
                if (MinMaxBoard[0][column] != (int)Mycell.Barren)
                    continue;
                int rowFilled = dropDisk(MinMaxBoard, column, color); // damage the state

                if (rowFilled == -1)
                    continue;
                int s = ScoreBoard(MinMaxBoard);

                if (s == (maximizeOrMinimize ? orangeWins : yellowWins))
                {
                    bestMove = column;
                    bestScore = s;
                    MinMaxBoard[rowFilled][column] = (int)Mycell.Barren;
                    break;
                }

                int moveInner, scoreInner;
                Minimax(!maximizeOrMinimize, color == (int)Mycell.Orange ? (int)Mycell.Yellow : (int)Mycell.Orange,
                depth - 1, MinMaxBoard, out moveInner, out scoreInner);

                MinMaxBoard[rowFilled][column] = (int)Mycell.Barren; // Undo the damage

                // No need for lists and sorting - just keep the best value you meet.
                if (maximizeOrMinimize)
                {
                    if (scoreInner >= bestScore)
                    {
                        bestScore = scoreInner;
                        bestMove = column;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (scoreInner <= bestScore)
                    {
                        bestScore = scoreInner;
                        bestMove = column;
                    }
                }

            }

            move = bestMove;
            score = bestScore;
        }
    }
  public int dropDisk(int[][] MinMaxBoard, int column, int color)
    {
        int y;
        for (y = height - 1; y >= 0; y--)
            if (MinMaxBoard[y][column] == (int)Mycell.Barren)
            {
                MinMaxBoard[y][column] = color;
                return y;
            }
        return -1;
    }
```

### edit:

I tried adding a method to tell whether the thread finished running:

```
    public bool TryGetValue(out int val)
    {

        val = ans;
        this.done = false;  
        if (done==true)
            return true;

        return false; 
    }
```

The thread has a public bool variable that gets initialized in `CompPlayTurn` so the thread initializes it with false for the first time

And just for testing it out, I set its value to true inside `CompPlayTurn`, the first thing it does (before the recursion and everything, right after the method signature).

And for the main thread I added:

```
  while (!(minimaxscript.TryGetValue(out column)))
                { StartCoroutine(wait(count)); }
```

and

```
 public IEnumerator wait(int count)
    {
        Debug.Log("not done yet");
        count++;
        if (count == 7)
        {
            Application.Quit();
            yield break;
        }
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(3f);
    }
```

I started with yield return new `WaitForEndOfFrame();` then yield return new `waitforseconds` and finally I added `Application.Quit()`

It freezes....I don;t think it is the thread, since he does't call the recourse...can;t be the main thread logic can it? it runs without the thread recursion ai just fine.

I even tried updating the bool variable to: `done=true` right after thread was created (`after the thread.start`) so it should be the main thread updating the variable before leaving the script, but it still freezes. as if the variable is never set....but without this protection I do get values, where are they coming from then?.

Nvm just lack of sleep -.- I am stupid...

this is the method I wanted to write and no idea what crossed my mind when I wrote what I did:

```
  public bool TryGetValue(out int val)
    {            
        val = ans;

        return done;
```

### }

edit: 
I changed the  done=false to be the first thing the thead does (first line in invoked method) and done=false, at the end of it.

Then main thread invokes waitforseconds(1f) and a debug msg to make sure it waits.

using this:

```
    bool ok = (minimaxscript.TryGetValue(out column));
                while (ok == false)
                {
                    ok = (minimaxscript.TryGetValue(out column));
                  StartCoroutine(  wait());
                }
```

And it freezes...

### final solution:

Adding the polling and protecting the method from invoking while it hasn;t finished yet seems to solve the problem.

The problem was eventually in unity, I kept calling the method again and again.
I was checking if it finished or not and coroutine it, but kept calling it regardless via a method that is called in update method so I didn;t notice that.

Comment: It's impossible to answer your question - it's confusing and lacking details. I suggest you update it with a clear description (including what's happening and what you expect to happen) and with actual code.

Comment: Sorry I tried to keep it simple as the answer I wanted was kinda yes or no, is it possible to run a method that calls a recursion by 1 thread (not main). The code is really long so that itself might be confusing, I don;t mind posting though if it helps

Comment: Does `CompPlayTurn` return any value or it is a void function? NVM. got it. it is a void function

Comment: Well it is inheriting from MonoBehaviour perhaps this is concidered unity api and prevents it from working as it would outside of unity? because in order to access it I need it as a script reference at the main script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question, yes you can recursively call a function and it will stay in the thread you just created.  Once you start that thread it no matter what function you call it will stay on that thread until it no longer has any code to execute.

However it looks like you are assigning a value to "ans" inside your `CompPlayTurn` function and then returning that value from `GetPCNextTurn`

The problem is that you can't guarantee that ans will be assigned before you return from that function (and most likely wont be).  When you create a new thread you have no guarantees of when each thread will finish doing work.  Which means that ans could be set before or after your return function, therefore making your return value no longer valid.

If you want to be able to return a value from a separate thread you will need to either pass a delegate to the function, or create a seperate function to poll when the value is set.  However be warned, anything that is unity specific can only be used from the main thread, so i would recommend using the polling function to return the value

```
public void GetPCNextTurn(int[][] board, int height, int width, int sequence)
{
    this.done = false;
    this.height = height;
    this.width = width;
    this.sequence = sequence;

    int[][] MinMaxBoard = CopyBoard(board);

    weights = GetWeights(sequence);
    Thread myThread = new Thread(() => CompPlayTurn(MinMaxBoard, weights));
    myThread.Start();
}

public bool TryGetValue(out int val) 
{
    //return true if you have a value and set that to val
}
```

This is a very rough implementation, as with anything multithreaded you will want to make this a lot more robust, I mainly wrote this to show you the concept

Comment: Thank you :) I needed a confirmation I was in the right direction as what I tried to do did not work, I tried to assign an out parameter (for the value returned) and a public bool so I can read it and know when the parameter is good.  I  will keep trying then.